# How to get cmake to create timestamp file after an actual build/link? (do nothing if executable hasn't changed)

Tags: cmake

I would like to invoke `date +"%s" > ${TIMESTAMP}` for each of the three executables, `myapp_data`, `myapp_live` and `myapp_sim` that I generate (ie only create the timestamp if the respective executables are created).

I can't seem to figure out why my custom command isn't being executed even after I remove the binaries and relink.  Build works fine - only the timestamp generation doesn't work.

```
MACRO( MY_APP TAG )
  SET( BINARY_TGT "myapp_${TAG}" )
  SET( TIMESTAMP  "TIMESTAMP_${TAG}" )
  ADD_EXECUTABLE( ${BINARY_TGT} ${APP_SRCS} )

  ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
    OUTPUT  ${TIMESTAMP}
    COMMAND date 
    ARGS    +\"%s\" > ${TIMESTAMP}
    DEPENDS ${BINARY_TGT}
  )
ENDMACRO( MY_APP )

SUBDIRS( data )
SUBDIRS( live )
SUBDIRS( sim  )
```

Inside the data dir, I have:

```
FILE(GLOB APP_SRCS RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} main_data.cpp)
SET( MY_TAG data )
MY_APP( "${MY_TAG}" )
```

Comment: Quoting is really painful in CMake.  Are you sure the command isn't attempting to run, but doing something other than you expect because of bad quoting?  Try running something else first, like `touch ${TIMESTAMP}`.  If you can get that to work, putting your date command in a separate script might be the easiest way to get to a working solution, rather than figuring out how to get redirects and quotes to make it through CMake correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMake does not run self-standing custom commands unless something depends on their output. One option is to change the custom command to a post-build:

```
add_custom_command(
  TARGET ${BINARY_TGT}
  POST_BUILD
  COMMAND date +\"%s\" > ${TIMESTAMP}
  VERBATIM
)
```

The other option is to add a custom target to drive the custom command(s). One target is sufficient for all custom commands.

```
add_custom_target(
  GenerateTimestamps ALL
  DEPENDS ${yourListOfTimestampFiles}
)
```

---

However, I am not sure if the redirecting will work as you expect. When you type `>` in a shell/command prompt, it's not an argument to the program, but an instruction to the shell/command processor. If it doesn't work (I've never tested), you'll have to put the invocation of `date` into a script.

Comment: `bash -c "date +\"%s\" > ${TIMESTAMP}"`is an option.

Comment: The command cmake executes, seems like bash command. I'm wondering about getting timestamp on Win/macOS/Linux. Is it possible to make it cross platform?