# How to build specific files in CMAKE everytime?

Tags: cmake

I am looking for a way to build some c, c++ files in CMAKE everytime when I type the make command whatever I modify the file or not. Because those file include build information codes such as build time. It this possible in CMAKE?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419255/how-to-get-cmake-to-create-timestamp-file-after-an-actual-build-link-do-nothin/13422476#13422476

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`add_custom_target`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_target) command to add a target that will be executed for every build.

For example, you can use the CMake [touch command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#opt%3a-E) to mark certain source files dirty, so they get rebuild on every run:

```
add_custom_target(invalidate_files ALL
                  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${MY_SRC_FILE})
```